# Copying random rows from one MySQL table to another MySQL table with a different schema

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cron

I have database table named `locations` that has many locations following this schema: `lid(PID), name, totalVotes, timeSince` and I want to randomly select 4 rows from this table and copy them into another table with a schema of `sid(PID), lid(Foreign), votes`. I want to set up a cron job to do this every day so I am first writing a PHP script to then be set up with the cron job later.

I am having problems getting the script to work though as no changes are being reflected in my selected database. Here is my attempt so far in `copy.php`:

```
<?php
  // create connection
  mysql_connect("localhost","root",NULL);
  @mysql_select_db("Locations") or die("Unable to select db");

  // this SQL statement moves 4 random rows from locations to selected table
  $sql = "INSERT INTO selected (lid) SELECT lid FROM locations WHERE lid IN (SELECT lid FROM locations ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4);";


  mysql_query($sql);
  mysql_close();
  echo "all good";
?>
```

When I refresh my `localhost/copy.php` I get the "all good" message, but again no changes in my `selected` table.

Comment: First off, are you trying to *move* or *copy*? I only see copying in your example.

Comment: @Piskvor copy, my apologies

Comment: use `mysql_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php to get truthness and check for errors. You're getting a false positive here and that means you have errors but you're not checking for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?
The first select is not needed and y think you have a  Bad **;** on thge end of the query.

```
INSERT INTO selected (lid) (SELECT lid FROM locations ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
```

Comment: *"and y think you have a Bad `;` on thge end of the query"* - `LIMIT 4);";` is valid syntax.